# AWS Task Definition container port

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am using a simple Dockerfile that will create an image and run a simple node.js application in port 3000.
This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I can access this from my local machine on port 3000.

Now I want to access this from an AWS ECS service and I've already created the necessary resources for this (Cluster/Task Def/ALB/Security Groups/Listener), but I am not sure how do I access this port 3000 from within AWS.

```
ECSTaskDefinition:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Family: !Join ["-", [!Ref ServiceName, taskdef, !Ref Environment]]
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Cpu: !Ref CPU
    Memory: !Ref Memory
    ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
    TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: !Sub
        - "${TheServiceName}-${TheEnvironment}"
        - TheServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
          TheEnvironment: !Ref Environment
    Image: !Ref Image
    Environment:
      - Name: AWS_ENV
        Value: !Ref Environment
      - Name: AWS_REGION
        Value: !Ref AWS::Region
    PortMappings:
      - ContainerPort: 80
        Protocol: tcp
    LogConfiguration:
      LogDriver: awslogs
      Options:
        awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
        awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
        awslogs-stream-prefix: !Sub ${ServiceName}-${Environment}

ApplicationLoadBalancer:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    IpAddressType: ipv4
    Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref Environment, !Ref AppNameForResources, "server"]]
    Scheme: internal
    LoadBalancerAttributes:
    - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
      Value: '30'
    SecurityGroups:
      - !Ref SecurityGroupForALB
    Subnets:
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ1-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ2-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
      - Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub
          - "${TheNetworkStackName}-PrivateAZ3-ID"
          - TheNetworkStackName: !Ref NetworkStackName
    Type: application

SecurityGroupForALB:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: !Sub 'Created for ALB of ${AppNameForResources} app on ${Environment}'
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '80'
        ToPort: '80'
        CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
        Description: 'HTTP Traffic to SG'
    VpcId: !Ref VPC

SecurityGroupForECS:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
    GroupDescription: !Sub 'Created for ECS ${AppNameForResources} app on ${Environment} env'
    SecurityGroupIngress:
      # Allow anything from SecurityGroupForALB
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '1'
        ToPort: '65535'
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt SecurityGroupForALB.GroupId
        Description: 'Accept anything from ALB security group'
    VpcId:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Join ['-', [!Ref NetworkStackName, 'VPCID']]

ALBTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub '${Environment}-${AppNameForResources}-alb-tg-1'
    HealthCheckEnabled: true
    HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
    HealthCheckPort: '80'
    HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
    HealthyThresholdCount: 2
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
    TargetType: ip
    VpcId:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NetworkStackName}-VPCID"

ALBListenerForHTTP:
  Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
    Port: 80
    Protocol: "HTTP"
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
```

There are Ports in these 2 security groups and also in my ALB and Target group.
How do I point my ALB to port 3000 here and where exactly in the stack should I make this change?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the ECS Task definition change the container port to `3000`:

```
    PortMappings:
      - ContainerPort: 3000
        Protocol: tcp
```

And change the Target Group port, and health check port settings to `3000`:

```
ALBTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub '${Environment}-${AppNameForResources}-alb-tg-1'
    HealthCheckEnabled: true
    HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
    HealthCheckPort: '3000'
    HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
    HealthyThresholdCount: 2
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
    Port: '3000'
```

After you make those changes, you can go to the load balancer's DNS address in your web browser, which will use the default HTTP port of `80`, and the load balancer will use the target group settings to forward the traffic to port `3000` of your ECS container.

Comment: Thank you. I assume there is no need for port changes in both Security groups. The SecurityGroupForALB is currently on Port 80 (Both From and To) and also for ALBListenerForHTTP

Comment: The `SecurityGroupForECS` is the one that needs port 3000 open, and you have **all** ports open in that group. So it will work as it is, although that's not the most secure configuraiton.

Comment: I made the change as suggested by you (Thanks again). Now the ECS service is not deploying(Keeps trying but failing). When I checked the CW logs I see this error "node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031
  throw err;Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/app.js''". So something wrong with my docker image that is running in ECS. My docker file is 1)FROM node:16-alpine 2)WORKDIR /usr/src/app 3)COPY package*.json ./ 4)RUN npm install COPY . . 5)EXPOSE 3000 6)CMD [ "node", "app.js" ] and I've "app.js" in my "src" folder.

Comment: I fixed the "Cannot find module" issue, the COPY in my Dockerfile should have been COPY ./src . instead of COPY ..
I checked the cloudwatch logs and it says "Example app listening on port 3000!"
But when I visit the ALB URL in a browser, it says "This site can’t be reached"
http://internal-dev-demo-ecs-poc-ui-server-1234567.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that was my mistake. I didn't include port ":3000" in my URL.
Its now working on http://internal-dev-demo-ecs-poc-ui-server-1234567.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:3000/

Should I always have that port 3000 appended to the URL whenever I visit the URL?

Comment: You posted this as an answer instead of a comment. Also, if it works with port 3000 appended, then you must have changed the port on the load balancer to port 3000 as well. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: must have been a comment

Comment: Yes, I changed the port on ALB to port 3000 via SecurityGroupForALB. Is there a better way to access the ALB DNS without appending port 3000? Not very sure where I should do the changes for this in my stack - Thanks